# Do we really need to instantiate the constructor in a method for Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

In Java Selenium why do I need to instantiate the constructor in the method?

```
public class Navigation extends BasePage {
public Navigation(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public Navigation visitUsSite() {
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.randomwebsite.com"));
    return new Navigation(driver);
}
}
```

Isn't the above just as valid as below:

```
public class Navigation extends BasePage {
public Navigation(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public void visitUsSite() {
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.randomwebsite.com");
}
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you try it ?

Comment: One returns a `Navigation` the other returns nothing. If you don't use the return value, there may be no difference *to you*, but they are definitely not the same. Btw, you don't return a constructor, nor instantiate a constructor. You use (call/invoke) the constructor to instantiate an object. Not the constructor, but the object instance is returned from the method.

Comment: I've executed both and they both work. I'm just curious as to why so many tutorials online suggest returning the constructer in the method?

Comment: @Samranator it is a good coding practise based on the concept of pageobjects. When you navigate away from a current page by clicking on a button or link, you want to return the pageobject of the new page to the calling method. In your case you are returning the same page so seems like a overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to return an instance of that class, but in many cases it's quite useful.
As @Grasshopper wrote in the comments, it's useful to already create an instance of the class that corresponds to a new page that you're opening. For example, you have a Login page that contains the following:
1) username field
2) password field
3) login button

The methods for entering the username and the password are as following:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    public LoginPage (WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public LoginPage enterUsername(String username) {
        WebElement usernameField = driver.findElementBy...;
        usernameField.sendKeys(username);
        return this; // returns this instance because it stays on the LoginPage
    }

    public LoginPage enterPassword (String password) {
        WebElement passwordField = driver.findElementBy...;
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
        return this; // returns this instance because it stays on the LoginPage
    }
}
```

Then you have a method that clicks on the login button, which redirects you to, let's say, homepage.

```
public HomePage clickLoginButton () {
        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElementBy...;
        loginButton.click();
        return new HomePage(driver); // returns a new instance on the HomePage because homepage will be opened
    }
```

The cool thing about returning 'this' instance and returning a new instance, is that in your test class, you can use your methods one after another, without having messy looking code:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
loginPage.enterUsername("username")
      .enterPassword("password");
HomePage homepage = loginPage.clickLoginButton();
```

Comment: That was very helpful! Learnt something new and it's nice to that step definition code can be made to look less verbose. Many thanks to you and @Grasshopper